# Get session data codeigniter from non codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have userid being sent over via a button click

```
<form action="https://www.mysite.co.uk/some/index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="ZUpmenVaN0ZVTTBmejNGZGNwZGFha1NmR0tuSjdaT3VYdjV5cTF4WGtISzRvK0ptOC9vZmQyc3J3T3cwTmplbWZ3alhod0xMYUhlQ2xLSng4WWI4ZEE9PQ2">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" style="font-size:14px; padding:20px;">
</form>
```

I then get the userid and use it within a normal php page (outsidecodeigniter)

**www.mysite.co.uk/some/index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['userid'])) {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        echo "You are logged in and have access to these tests.";?>

code here

    <?php
    } else {
        header ('location: ../index.htm');
    }
    ?>
```

I now need to use userid within a controller that sends data to a data base in code igniter

**ci controller**

```
 private function getResults()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $_POST['userid']);
        $userID = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $score = $this->actions->getSentEmailCount();
        $percentilescore = $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
        $testID = '134';

        {
            $data['emailcount'] = $score = $this->actions->getEmailCount();
            $data['sentEmailCount'] = $score = $this->actions->getSentEmailCount();
            $data['score'] = $score = $this->actions->getScore();
            $data['percentile'] = $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
            $data['timespent'] = $this->input->get('time');
        };

        $adddata = array(
            'uniID' => '5',
            'testName' => 'Abintegro E-Tray test',
            'testID' => $testID,
            'total' => '20',
            'useInPercentile' => '1',
            'correct' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percent' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percentile' => $percentilescore,
            'dateTaken' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'timeSpent' => $this->input->get('time'),
            'userID' => $userID
        );

        $this->actions->add_record($adddata);
        return $this->load->view('client/results', $data);
    }
```

I get a error

> Message: Undefined index: userid

can some one see why I am getting null ?

Comment: What's the error message? Try `var_dump($_SESSION)` is it there? or your **this.php** doesn't work correctly.

Comment: get null, im loosing the value somewhere

Comment: Probably, you are resetting your session's global variable.

Comment: hmm ok, thanks. ill look through the code where the session may restart

Comment: Just put this `$this->load->library('session');` and don't call this `session_start(); ` anywhere else.

Comment: ive only used session_start(); outside the ciproject, i need this for outside ci

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're working outside the CI directory, `$_SESSION` is a global variable and it can be reached anywhere.

Comment: nice, +1 thanks ill try it out

Answer (score 2):

As you set the session in custom PHP, you can not retrive it from CI. You have to retrive it from from custom PHP.
LIKE::

```
session_start();
$userID = $_SESSION['userid'];
```

Reference::
[Session Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: yes please replace "$userID = $this->session->userdata('userid');" with

"session_start();
$userID = $_SESSION[userid];"
It will works.

Comment: Thanks, looks sweet and simple ill implement this and get back to you.

Comment: Getting a error Use of undefined constant userid - assumed 'userid' but ill try and fix that then accept your answer

Comment: First check your session value is set or not.
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
die;

Comment: hmm im not getting anything. ill debug this and get back to this answer. thank you

Comment: How to call that model function in your page??
check the url actually going to that model or not.

Comment: myfunction.php is a controller and my model is  $this->db->insert('myfunction', $data);
            return;

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to start session using codeigniter library
Just call :

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then set your session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $_POST['userid']);
```

Then access session variable in your function,

```
private function getResults()
    {
        $score = $this->actions->getSentEmailCount();
        $userID = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $percentilescore = $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
        $testID = '134';

        $adddata = array(
            'uniID' =>  $userID,
            'testName' => 'Abintegro E-Tray test',
            'testID' => $testID,
            'total' => '20',
            'useInPercentile' => '1',
            'correct' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percent' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percentile' => $percentilescore,
            'dateTaken' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'timeSpent' => $this->input->get('time'),
            'userID' => $userID
        );
$this->actions->add_record($adddata);
        return $this->load->view('client/results', $data);
}
```

[Refer here for more..](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Ok, pop this all in the function ?

Comment: Yes, it will work. But better you can put $this->load->library('session'); in your class constructor

Comment: hmm keep getting Message: Undefined index: userid, ill keep at it

Comment: what is the result of var_dump($this->session->userdata()); ?

Comment: ["user_id"]=> NULL  that is strange as when is use  the new code ive just added to the question i get the userid

Comment: Check whether you are getting $_GET['userid'] without null

Comment: can you var_dump($_GET['userid']) ?

Comment: I have and i get null, ive added the full code i use in a page outside codeignigter to get the userid

Comment: Can you show me the url used for getting $_GET['userid'] ?

Comment: Ok, I just want to know the url you are calling for execute the function

Comment: OK I have updated the code to include the full code base

Comment: You are using POST request, use $_POST['userid']. I've updated the answer

Comment: getting Undefined index: userid on line $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $_POST['userid']);